# Getting Invalid Identifier error while getting Maximum ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in Oracle. I have no record in Database and I am trying to get *max(col_name)* but it returns invalid Identifier value. How to deal with it?

Comment: please post the code/query you've tried!!

Comment: Invalid identifier means you might be giving wrong table name or column name.

Comment: It is a bit lame but Unlike MySQL Oracle asks Function and Expression as STRING in double qoutation:  *select "MAX"("sb_id") from TABLE*

Comment: You might be new to Oracle, but you aren't new to SO. Surely you know what makes a good question by now? Your comment happens to indicate what is wrong, but it would have been clear earlier if you'd posted the code, actual error message and table definition, since your question gives us nothing to go on. I'd also suggest you try not to think too much about how other databases work, and look at the free online documentation to get started.

Comment: @AlexPoole I do agree with you and pardon for not following guidelines properly

Comment: @Volatil3 - think I woke up grumpy this morning... shouldn't really comment before coffee...

Comment: No worries. No offense taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oracle asks Function and Expression as STRING in double qoutation

It doesn't generally do that... certainly not for standard built-in function names like `MAX`.

You only have to use doube quotes around object names that were defined with [quouted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm).

From your comment it appears that your table was created something like:

```
create table "TABLENAME" ("sub_id" number, ...);
```

... which would mean you will always have to use double-quotes around the column name whenever you refer to it. That will continue to be a pain and cause you problems, so I'd really recommend that you don't ever use mixed-case names or anything else that requires quoting like that.

If unquoted identifiers are used (or the quoted name is uppercase anyway, like `"SUB_ID"`) then Oracle is case-insensitive and any of these would be valid:

```
select max(sb_id) from ...
select max(SB_ID) from ...
select max(Sb_Id) from ...
```

etc.